# "Aborting producer batches due to fatal error" in Kafka streams after killing broker

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

During a test where we simulate the failure of a single Kafka broker in a cluster of 6, there were warnings with ProducerFencedExceptions in all our Streams apps (all of which are running in exactly_once_beta mode), which is fair enough. In one of those apps however, there also was also an error:

> "2021-03-02 11:03:13.690","ERROR","kafka-producer-network-thread | my-kafka-streams-c29c733a-4838-4787-9bce-7c83c31710e9-StreamThread-2-producer","org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender","[Producer clientId=my-kafka-streams-c29c733a-4838-4787-9bce-7c83c31710e9-StreamThread-2-producer, transactionalId=my-kafka-streams-c29c733a-4838-4787-9bce-7c83c31710e9-2] **Aborting producer batches due to fatal error**","e5d2ab183d14","my-kafka-streams-5636eaa5-a956-35b9-6f6e-b3418918e74b","my-kafka-streams","HOST123","3193","1614650593690536","0","2021-03-02 11:03:13.690","org.apache.kafka.common.errors.**ProducerFencedException: Producer attempted an operation with an old epoch. Either there is a newer producer with the same transactionalId, or the producer's transaction has been expired by the broker.**

1. So is this in fact what it looks like - data loss?
2. How can this be avoided?